# windows webmatrix TYPO3 Backend partly invisible

Tags: windows, typo3, backend

I have installed TYPO3 6.2 with Webmatrix on my windows Laptop.
I could work for a while successfully.
Now I have this strange problem with the Backend:
I can log in  and I see my pages with their content in the backend.
If I try to go to edit the properties of a page I only see a grey main area.
I can reload and the area is back again.
The same happens if I want to insert a new ContentElement.
I see the different CE but if I choose one -- I get this grey empty area.
The Modules are still visible, the PageTree is visible, only the main area is grey.
I can not remember what I have done before this starts to happen.
I have of course emptied the caches.

Does anybody has an idea?
Thank you very much in advance.
Stefan

Comment: Check the error log, maybe you are running out of memory or something. Also enable the debug mode in the Install Tool, maybe that makes an error message show up.

Comment: HI Jost, debug mode saved my day. Message showed an Extension which produced the error. I deinstalled the extension and it's ok again.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

debug mode saved my day. Message showed an Extension which produced the error. I deinstalled the extension and it's ok again.
Thank you very much.